# Где брать знания дальше?

Tags: c#

Hello HashCode, вот скажите я прочитал 4 книги по C# многое понял и освоил, но вот к примеру открыл эмулятор серверов онлайн игры, там я там понял 10-15% кода, остальное не известно. Так вот где взять те знания которых не было в книгах? А то ооочень хочется делать эмуляторы серверов :)

Answer (score 8):

1. поставь себе цель.
2. Придумай на листике бумаги как она будет работать ( типо как в Doxygen картинки показывает )
3. Начни это делать.
4. В процессе ты поймешь, что схема построена местами не верно, попробуешь ее переделать.
5. Начнешь писать дальше, столкнешься с проблемой характера "Ой, а чо дельше делать, как лучше поступить, а что для этого нужно ? "
6. Полезешь в интернеты чтобы ответить на вопрос п.5
7. Со временем твои скилы прокачаются и ты получишь опыт и кучу экспы за труд.

Поздравляю, именно так и получают ответы на те вопросы, которые ранее казались супер-мега тяжеленными :)

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы задаёте такие вопросы, я бы посоветовал либо попробовать сначала сделать что-нибудь попроще, чтобы было общее представление о том, как решается задача, и изучать требовалось только отдельные вопросы, либо искать работу, на которой занимаются тем, чем Вам интересно. Опытные коллеги подскажут.